# Can cancel onclick event after blur(focusout)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Because I have a check function, and check function happens in textarea when blur and click save button.
All things are good except one case. When I in textarea, I directly click the button. This will happen twice check (first check to happen in a blur, and then happen in onclick event). I don't like it.

I solve this problem using two methods.
1: Use one flag to detect whether check before. When click saves button, check this flag.
2: Use mouse-down replaces of onclick method and event.preventDefault. This first check will happen mouse-down, and not trigger blur.

I think the other method. Firs check happens in a blur, and then "not" happen in onclick event. So I want to know Can cancel onclick event after blur(focus out)?  If not why? (I don't know how to cancel or I don't find solutions. Thanks.

Code like

```
    blur() {
        checkfunction();
    }

    onclick() {
        checkfunction();
        save();
    }
```

Comment: Please don't use elements meant to structure a post for decoration purposes.

Comment: To answer your question, you cannot cancel one event from a separate event. To solve your issue you need to re-structure your code and its associated event handlers. As you've not shown the code, we cannot help you with that

Comment: why I can not cancel one event from a separate event? But I can use mouse-down replaces of onclick method and event.preventDefault. This first check will happen mouse-down, and not trigger blur. I think this mean I can stop blur event by event.preventDefault.

Comment: Because the first event will probably have already have finished being handled when the second fires. Aside from that there's no mechanism in JS to allow you to do it

Comment: @ the4kman why don't? thanks.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan
But I can use mouse-down replaces of onclick method and event.preventDefault. This first check will happen mouse-down, and not trigger blur. I think this mean I can stop blur event by event.preventDefault. Was I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `event.stopPropagation();`
example:

```
blur(){
    // code textarea
};
onclick(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    // code button
};
```

Comment: It's does not work on my computer. Do u test it? In my chrome, the order is blur first, and onclick second. And put stopPropagation in blur can not stop onclick event.

Comment: `blur` event has been started, if you want stop it, you can check a flag var for it and set in `onclick` event.

Comment: I want stop onclick, when blur started.

Comment: example :  in `blur()`, you set `var check_blur_start = true;` and in `onclick` you check `check_blur_start`, when `blur()` finished you set `check_blur_start = false;`

Comment: or you disable this button when `blur()`

Comment: thank u, I have written this solve method in question.
1: Use one flag to detect whether check before. When click saves button, check this flag.
You said disable this button when blur(), do u try this and success?

Comment: disable this button when blur(). Ok, it works, although it will cause the other problem caused the button disable. But it can use relatedTarget check to solve, thanks.